# How to write a nested dictionary to a csv with newlines such that each line contains a key and value

Tags: csv, dictionary, nested, writer

I need to write a nested dictionary to a csv file, I have some functions that work well for a non-nested dict but I keep running into problems with the nested dict because I don't understand what I'm doing and although I have found some similar problems here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199304/how-can-i-write-a-nested-dictionary-to-a-csv-file)I cannot see where to apply the necessary change.

**I want this dict**:

```
my_dict = {1: {50: 6, 150: 5, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1},
            2: {50: 5.8, 150: 5, 250: 6.3, 350:5.5, 450: 5.9},
            3: {50: 6, 150: 5.8, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1},
            4: {50: 6.1, 150: 5.6, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1}}
```

**To be written like this**:

```
Row Chip Voltage
1   50  6
1   150 5
1   250 6
1   350 5.5
1   450 6.1
...

4   50  5.8
```

**Code I have so far**:

```
from csv import writer
from csv import DictWriter


my_dict = {1: {50: 6, 150: 5, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1},
            2: {50: 5.8, 150: 5, 250: 6.3, 350:5.5, 450: 5.9},
            3: {50: 6, 150: 5.8, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1},
            4: {50: 6.1, 150: 5.6, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1}}

def csv_with_headers(filename, headers):
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer_object = writer(f)
        writer_object.writerow(headers)
        f.close()


def append_csv(filename, mydict, headers):
    """ Open csv file and append a dictionary of drop properties to the
    available filenames."""
    field_names = headers
    # Open your CSV file in append mode, Create a file object for this file
    with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as f_object:
        # Pass the file object and a list  of column names to DictWriter()
        # You will get a object of DictWriter
        dictwriter_object = DictWriter(f_object, fieldnames=field_names)
        # Pass the dictionary as an argument to the Writerow()
        dictwriter_object.writerow(mydict)
        # Close the file object
        f_object.close()


   
headers = ["Row", "Chip", "Voltage"]
csv_with_headers('mycsvfile2.csv', headers)

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for ki, vi in v.items():
        append_csv('mycsvfile2.csv', v, headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it and outputted data to the csv exactly as I wanted it.

**Solution:**

```
from csv import writer
from csv import DictWriter


my_dict = {1: {50: 6, 150: 5, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1},
            2: {50: 5.8, 150: 5, 250: 6.3, 350:5.5, 450: 5.9},
            3: {50: 6, 150: 5.8, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1},
            4: {50: 6.1, 150: 5.6, 250: 6, 350:5.5, 450: 6.1}}


def csv_with_headers(filename, headers):
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer_object = writer(f)
        writer_object.writerow(headers)
        f.close()

   
headers = ["Row", "Chip", "Voltage"]
csv_with_headers('mycsvfile3.csv', headers)
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    print(k, " : ", v)
    for ki, vi in v.items():
        stuff = [k, ki, vi]
        print('\n'*3,"stuff : ", stuff)
        with open('mycsvfile3.csv','a', newline='') as f:
            write = writer(f)
            write.writerow(stuff)
```