# Writing a Python Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

hope you can help me with this.

I have a **nested** dictionary like this:

```
Inventory = {'devicename': {'Interface1': {'port_setting1': 'value', 'port_setting2': 'value'}, 'Interface2': {'port_setting1': 'value', 'port_setting2': 'value'}}}
```

I want to create a csv out of that with the following format:

```
devicename, interface1, value of port_setting1, value of portsetting2
devicename, interface2, value of port_setting1, value of portsetting2
```

Can you help me how to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: loop through the dictionary and write line to csv file.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798987/write-nested-dictionary-to-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the dictionary to a pandas dataframe. This can then be exported as a csv without the column names to achieve what you require.

The following code snippet would do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): Inventory[i][j] 
                           for i in Inventory.keys() 
                           for j in Inventory[i].keys()},
                       orient='index')
df.to_csv('test.csv', header = False)
```

This is how your `test.csv` looks like for the dictionary called `Inventory` you have shown in the question:

```
devicename,Interface1,value,value
devicename,Interface2,value,value
```

Comment: Do you know why Panda formats a single decimal value like 90 to 90.0 in the csv?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe because one column would have a single datatype (like `int` or `float`). Check this thread to see how to change datatypes of a column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291259/convert-floats-to-ints-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `dict` and `print` in a file:

```
with open(filename.csv, 'w') as fh:
    for k, v in Inventory.items():
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            print(k, k1, *v1.values(), file=fh, sep=', ')
```

Or in a comprehension:

```
with open(filename.csv, 'w') as fh:
    print(*(', '.join((k, k1, *v1.values())) 
           for k, v in Inventory.items() 
           for k1, v1 in v.items()), 
           file=fh, sep='\n'
     )
```

Output:

```
devicename, Interface1, value, value
devicename, Interface2, value, value
```